# Educational game from the 1980s about building machines that manipulate words or numbers

Tags: identify-this-game

OK so this is really old school. Back in the 1980s, as a latchkey kid, I played on the computers in the library in elementary and middle school. There was this one bizarre educational game that I'd love to find more about.

It involved connecting a bunch of nodes with wires, creating a big rube goldberg contraption that did things to words or numbers. Press the play button and stuff pops out of some of the nodes, travels along all the little conveyer belts, interacts in some other nodes, and pops out in various places. It was a very "just play with it and see what it does" kind of game. I forget if there was even a purpose, like being required to get a certain output into a bucket or something.

"The Incredible Machine" is close but no cigar. It's not falling objects in a literal rube goldberg machine, it's squares connected by wires, like some modern day audio-processing pro software:

[image]

But this was a kiddie game. Mid-80s.

Cross-posted on Mathematics Education: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/20888/looking-for-an-educational-game-from-long-ago-possibly-called-mother-goose

Comment: Mixed Up Mother Goose is educational but it doesn't seem to match the description you're making of it, so it's not related

Comment: Oh wasn't it "The Incredible Machine" ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTbSMKGQ_rU&ab_channel=Dosgamert

Comment: very good thought, this is similar, but about a decade later than i remember. however this is close!

Comment: some recs from another thread are rocky's boots and gertrude's secrets/puzzles. those are closer to the era, but maybe too early as they're lower res than i remember.

Comment: It might help if you could add the system it was played on.

Comment: I think it's likely the game will be low res if it were from the 80s.

Comment: Previously asked at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/20888/77).

Comment: sorry about not updating the cross posting - i added it to both questions. this has not been successfully answered in either location.

Comment: maybe you can delete the other crosspost then

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't *Rocky's Boots*, then it sounds like one of the ***Reader Rabbit*** games, like *Word Factory* or *Reader Rabbit 2*.

I'm not too familiar with them, but *Reader Rabbit* games seem to revolve around series of minigames involving reassembling words, moving them about in factories and various match-up games.

Bear in mind that there are a *lot* of *Reader Rabbit* games, all with different minigames, so you should look through screenshots of them all to see if you can find your node-drawing game among them.

[image]

Comment: good thought but this isn't it. there's a "connect nodes with wires" aspect. just like the example i gave above.